# Resolve potential memory leak of an object

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

After using the analyze tool in xcode, I found the below warning in my code. (line 58 and line 61)

[image]

How can I fix the leakages in this cases?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code; that just makes it hard to read. At least take the time to copy-paste it. You can indicate the line on which you're getting the notice with a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Xcode is confused over where to draw the highlight lines, the actual errors reported by clang are on line 54 and line 66.

ABAddressBookCreate() needs to be balanced by a CFRelease() when you are done using the address book:

```
if (addressBook) CFRelease(addressBook)
```

Your ABRecordCopyValue() variables also need to be released at the end of the loop block:

```
if (fName) CFRelease(fName);
if (lName) CFRelease(lName);
```

C functions which return ...Ref objects and contain "Create" or "Copy" generally need to be balanced by a CFRelease().  If the function contains "Get", it is usually an inside pointer or already in an autorelease pool.